# Get the catalina.base property from command line for Tomcat 5.0

Tags: tomcat

I need to read the catalina.base property for Tomcat 5.0.

For Tomcat 5.5 and above, I can obtain this from the executable path of the java process where catalina.base is mentioned as a system property.

However in Tomcat 5.0, the catalina.base property is mentioned as "..". Hence, I'm not able to get the exact directory path for the catalina base location.

How can I solve this problem?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Just in case... is this on Windows, Linux or what OS?

Answer (score 0):

Use the environment variable:

```
echo %CATALINA_BASE%
```

**References**

- [Running Tomcat as a Windows Service](https://blogs.oracle.com/ideas/entry/running_tomcat_as_a_windows)